# Neural network playground

Tags: dynamic, machine-learning, neural-networks

I came across this [Neural Net Playground](http://playground.tensorflow.org/#activation=tanh&batchSize=10&dataset=circle&regDataset=reg-plane&learningRate=0.03&regularizationRate=0&noise=0&networkShape=4,2&seed=0.46284&showTestData=false&discretize=false&percTrainData=50&x=true&y=true&xTimesY=false&xSquared=false&ySquared=false&cosX=false&sinX=false&cosY=false&sinY=false&collectStats=false&problem=classification) demonstration based on Google's Tensorflow package. It visualizes the data processing inside a neural network and allows you to tweak parameters and immediately see:

[image]

***Has anyone built something like this in Mathematica with dynamic expressions or Manipulates?***

This would really help increase my intuition and visual understanding of what exactly goes on inside these nets during training and how various parameters affect performance.

Comment: [Simulating Neural Networks with Mathematica](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Books/3485/) (1994)

Comment: That's a very nice web app, I don't think you'll find anything in Mathematica that will be as well produced.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen that's a nice book but 22 years is a bit old :)

Comment: @RunnyKine not sure what functionally is built in already and exposed that I can use in this fashion, Classify with method "NeuralNetwork" obfuscates a lot of the training process details

Comment: I don't know if you noticed the smiley at the end of that question.

Comment: `TrainingProgressReporting` can provide the real-time visualization.

Comment: I think you may get more help adding information what do you expect behind the scene and what is behind every GUI element, this problem may be solvable by someone who does not know so much about neural networks but knows GUI construction well. By lack of effort you are limiting the possibility of getting the answer. (I assumed you know the topic enough to be able to provide such information)